# Best place to put the HTML purifier library?

Tags: php, html, security, htmlpurifier

This might be a really silly question but where is the best place to put the HTML purifier library?

I am assuming if I put it in public_html then someone with ill intent could easily access it, should I put it in a folder that is on the same par level as public_html? maybe make a special folder for it? Or should I be placing it completely outside the document root?

Comment: Oh crap, I didnt realise.....sorry, newb at this, ill go do that for my previous posted questions as well, sorry guys!!

Comment: Most libraries like this are a collection of classes and functions. Odds are nothing is executed if someone calls the PHP files remotely. Check the source to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You already named a few. The first way is to just place it outside the web root so no-one can acces it. The second one (the one I always use) is to create a new folder for the file and place a .htaccess in it with the following content:

```
Deny from all
```

This allows you to include the file with php but not to call it directly from your browser.

If you want to know more about the second method, take a look at this [link](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/htaccess-deny-from-all-restrict-directory-access.html).

Comment: Does that mean then I could create a folder WITHIN public_html, put a text file called htaccess in that directory, with Deny from all and its safe? , I noticed I already have this file, does it matter if there are multiple htaccess files in various folders? (P.S that is an awesome link, very useful thankyou!)

Comment: Make sure the file is called .htaccess, not htaccess. You can have multiple .htaccess files on your server, just make sure they are not in the same directory. And you answer your question: yes, it works that way. You can always test it by trying to call one off the files from your browser.